# Vuetify Menu not working: Property or method “on” is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: menu, vuetify.js

I am copying [an first example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus) from the official documentation Vuetify about Menus, but the result is an error :

> "Property or method "on" is not defined on the instance but referenced
>   during render".

```js
<template>
        <v-app>
            <div class="text-xs-center">
                <v-menu offset-y>
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                        <v-btn
                                color="primary"
                                dark
                                v-on="on"
                        >
                            Dropdown
                        </v-btn>
                    </template>
                    <v-list>
                        <v-list-tile
                                v-for="(item, index) in items"
                                :key="index"
                                @click=""
                        >
                            <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
                        </v-list-tile>
                    </v-list>
                </v-menu>
            </div>
        </v-app>
    </template>
    
    <script>
        export default {
            data: () => ({
                items: [
                    { title: 'Click Me' },
                    { title: 'Click Me' },
                    { title: 'Click Me' },
                    { title: 'Click Me 2' }
                ]
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087618/vue-js-vuetify-menu-named-slot-activator-is-not-binding-to-the-template-but-g

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue in Vuetyfy 1.4.4 and Vue 2.5. Updating this packages fixed problem.
In vue 2.6.9 and vuetify 1.5.6 attribute v-slot:activator="{ on }" works great.
Check your outdated packages by
`npm outdated --depth=0`
and then update them by
`npm update vuetyfy vue etc`.

Comment: I got this issue too yesterday and everything started to work after running `npm update`

Comment: I experimentally found out that this was fixed in Vue 2.6.4.

Answer (score 1):

In my case work but browser showed warning, adding **on** prop remove warning for me using vuetify 2.2.4

```
props: ['on']
```

*Edit*: My problem was that I was using `v-on="on"` outside of template that was declaring with **v-slot**, remove it worked for me