# Vue JS Vuetify menu named slot "activator" is not binding to the template, but going to "default"

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, babeljs, vuetify.js

I cannot seem to get the example code for a Vuetify v-menu to work inside my PWA app, but it works normally in a Fiddle (e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/tjw13yz4/27/)

The problem is: the activator slot content doesn't appear.

By debugging the vuetify source code, I have found that the activator template turns up under the "default" slot (where all the hidden content is), not in the named activator slot (where the visible button/click area should be).

I have simplified my app to the bare bones (originally I had dynamic components, forms, APIs etc) so I've reduced it down to just a v-menu inside the top-level v-app element, and removed all the routers, stores and other plugins. It's as simple as I can get it, but still doesn't work. the only difference left between the fiddle and my local app is the build system.

I have also tried changing/removing the slot props and the `on` binding through to the button, which does modify how the named slot is internally represented in Vuetify (or Vue). However neither verison with or without props binds the named-slot properly.

I also npm updated and rebuilt (suggested in another SO), so I'm on the latest Vue 2.6.10 and Vuetify 1.5.14.

I have also ensured I am wrapping in `<v-app></v-app>` (but that happened when I installed the Vuetify plugin) as noted in other SO's.

I also read [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188478/meaning-of-v-slotactivator-on) which I found useful in debugging.

I've tried putting `slot=activator` directly on HTML tag, rather than using the template.

And I probably tried a dozen other things, (initially I just had a problem with the `on` for v-on not being defined, but it was due to this underlying problem).

These are my simplified files - it's all pretty standard:

App.vue (with/out props for on-event binding)

```
<template>
  <v-app>

    <v-menu offset-y>
      <template v-slot:activator>
        <v-btn color="primary" dark>Dropdown</v-btn>
      </template>

      <p>The menu content</p>
    </v-menu>

    <v-menu offset-y>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn color="primary" v-on="on" dark>Dropdown2</v-btn>
      </template>

      <p>The menu2 content</p>
    </v-menu>

  </v-app>
</template>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import "./plugins/vuetify";
import App from "./App.vue";
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

plugins/vuetify.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'md',
})
```

index.html

When it runs, I set a breakpoint in `node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VMenu/mixins/menu-generators.js` and it returns null here because neither type of slots are set:

```
    genActivator: function genActivator() {
        if (!this.$slots.activator && !this.$scopedSlots.activator) return null;
```

**In my app**, the Chrome debug inspector shows the `v-btn` is next to the `p` tag under the `default` `$slot`, but it should be under its own one.

[image]

**In the working Fiddle** by contrast, when debugging the same function, I see the `activator` node under `$scopeSlots` when I include the v-on=on event binding, and under the `$slots` if not. And it works fine.

[image]

Why might the `v-slot=activator` statement not take effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reading this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55268990/209288 I found that the older (pre Vue v2.6) syntax worked OK, both in my stripped-down app, and then also in place in my original component.

```
<template slot="activator" slot-scope="{ on }">
```

Therefore I realised my app must have still been running an older version, even though I'd used the "Build" option in the Vui UI after doing the npm update.

I just **stopped and re-started the `vue-cli-service serve`** command (in the UI) and now it all works as expected!

So I guess **I was still running Vue v2.5.22** and the build from VSCode was just hot-reloading some parts.

So the lesson is: after doing an npm update, shut down and restart everything, the build server, VSCode debugger, chrome instance.

Comment: In my case, I had a dependency in our build chain that was keeping vue back.